# Profiling Ratpack: ExecControllerBindingThreadFactory high CPU usage and lots of threads

Tags: multithreading, ratpack

We have a mobile app API server written with Ratpack 1.5.1 about to go live soon, and we're currently profiling the application to catch any performance bottlenecks. The app is backed by an SQL database and we're careful to always run queries using the `Blocking` class. The code is written in Kotlin and we wrote some coroutine glue code to force blocking operations to be executed on Ratpack's blocking threads.

Since Ratpack's thread model is unique we'd like to make sure this situation is normal: we simulated 2500 concurrent users of the application and our thread count went up to 400 (and even 600 at one point), most of these being `ratpack-blocking-x-yyy` threads.

Sampling the CPU we get 92% time spent in the `ratpack.exec.internal.DefaultExecController$ExecControllerBindingThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0` method, but this could be an artifact of sampling.

So, to ask concrete questions: given Ratpack's thread model, is the high blocking thread count normal and should we be worrying about the high CPU time spent in the above mentioned method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ratpack creates unlimited(*) thread-pool for blocking operations. It gets created in `DefaultExecController`:

```
public DefaultExecController(int numThreads) {
    this.numThreads = numThreads;
    this.eventLoopGroup = ChannelImplDetector.eventLoopGroup(numThreads, new ExecControllerBindingThreadFactory(true, "ratpack-compute", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY));
    this.blockingExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ExecControllerBindingThreadFactory(false, "ratpack-blocking", Thread.NORM_PRIORITY));
}
```

Threads that are created in this pool don't get killed right after blocking operation is done - they are idling in the pool and waiting for the next job to do. The main reason behind it is that keeping thread in idle state is cheaper than spawning new threads when they are needed. That's why when you simulate 2500 concurrent users calling and endpoint which executes blocking operation, you will see 2500 threads in this pool. Cached thread-pool that gets created uses following `ThreadPoolExecutor` object:

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 2147483647, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue(), threadFactory);
}
```

where `2147483647` is maximum pool size, `60L` is TTL expressed in seconds. It means that executor service will keep those threads for 60 seconds and when they don't get re-used after 60 seconds, it will clean them up.

High CPU in this case is actually expected. 2500 threads are utilizing a few cores of the CPU. It's also important - where your SQL database is running? If you run it on the same machine then your CPU has even harder job to do. If the operations you run on blocking thread-pool are consuming significant CPU time, then you have to optimize those blocking operations. Ratpack's power comes with async and non-blocking architecture - handlers use `ratpack-compute` thread-pool and delegate all blocking operations to `ratpack-blocking` so your application is not blocked and can handle tons of requests.

(*) unlimited in this case means limited by available memory or if you have enough memory it is limited by `2147483647` threads (this value is used in `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool(factory)`).

Comment: Thank you, I understand what is going on better now. For this test we are running the database on the same server, but the prod server uses a database on another machine.

Comment: @GregorPetrin Try simulating prod environment then. Blocking operation that executes DB query towards remote server wont consume much CPU - thread will wait for the response for most of the time. I was running 100k requests executed for a few minutes where blocking operation didn't consume much of CPU and I was getting about 7% CPU usage. It would give me much different result if my blocking operation would actually run some CPU consuming operations.

Comment: I will, but prod is still running an old version that matches the testers' versions and it's running an old protocol, no metrics etc.. will test when possible, thank you for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on Szymon's answer…

Ratpack doesn't inherently throttle any operations. That's effectively up to you. One option you have is to use https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/exec/Throttle.html to constrain and queue access to a resource.

Comment: No, that's OK, we don't need to throttle anything, the database should hold its own (if it doesn't, we need to optimize there, not on Ratpack's side). My main takeaway was that the many threads are perfectly normal as long as they don't do much actual work and this also seems to explain the profiler always catching work inside the `ExecControllerBindingThreadFactory` class (i.e. I'm more assured that we're not doing anything wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the input, Luke!